# Simple in memory file system

Tags: filesystems, operating-system, osdev

Can anybody point me to a simple (can't stress this enough) implementation of an in memory file system? If I can create a file and do a simple cat file.txt it's more than enough.

I would like to use it as part of my toy OS.

Comment: if you were writing an OS, wouldn't you start with the file system?

Comment: If it will be closed then so be it, but at least tell me the reason.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, surprisingly not, booting, setting up stuff like gdt, idt, isr, printing, irq's, paging ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, in-memory  file systems should be as basic as possible.  Here is a virtual file system implemented in user-mode from Windows, but its design principals can be used in your own OS. http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Programming_a_Virtual_File_System-Part_I.shtml .  Even this might be too much for your basic OS.  I say just wing it and create a linked list of file descriptors that include only file attributes, file name, and file path with each file.

Answer (score 3):

[The OSDev wiki site](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) might help you. You can also ask your questions there and if you look at wiki and [their forum](http://forum.osdev.org/) you will pretty likely get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This belongs on Super User IMHO, but anyway, you might want to look at [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/). It should be more than enough for just creating a RAM disk.</strike>

Wait, I misread... this is for your "toy OS"? Your toy OS supports file systems? You're going to have to implement it yourself, since there's no way something preexisting will work with your home-made OS.

Comment: There are quite a few people implementing simple operating system, I was wondering if someone could point me to one that has already added some basic filesystem support, I know I will have to implement it myself.